# How is "class.object.function" implemented in python?

Tags: python, class

So in Pandas we can do `str` operations on a string column like

```py
str_lower = df["str_col"].str.lower()
```

I wonder, how is the `str.lower()` implemented in a class (note it is not about the *specific* implementation of `str.lower()` but more how such a thing would be implemented in python generally)?

The only thing I can think of, Is a method of a sub-class defined in the class e.g

```py
class DataFrame():
     class str():
           def lower(self):
                 return [p.lower() for p in self.column]
```

but I doubt it's correct

Comment: I imagine you could achieve this using a `__getattr__` as well. Of course, I have no idea if that's what Pandas actually does

Answer (score 1):

Since Pandas is open source, you can find the code on Github! [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ad190575aa75962d2d0eade2de81a5fe5a2e285b/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py#L1) is the .str implementation page. The `_map_and_wrap` function provides a nice way of understanding what's happening, start with it and go deeper!

```
def _map_and_wrap(name, docstring):
    @forbid_nonstring_types(["bytes"], name=name)
    def wrapper(self):
        result = getattr(self._data.array, f"_str_{name}")()
        return self._wrap_result(result)

    wrapper.__doc__ = docstring
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it uses `property`, it allows you to get the return value of a function like a attribute:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...         self.lst = list(args)
...     @property
...     def string(self):
...         return ' '.join(map(str, self.lst))
...
>>> f = Foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> f.string
'1 2 3 4 5'
>>> f.string.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

The essence of `property` is to wrap a function into a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). You can consider learning about it.